# When to mount /tmp (and other temporary directories)

Tags: debian, mount, fstab, tmp, init.d

When is the right time to mount `/tmp` (on Debian)? For `/home` I would not feel bad just to `echo "/dev/foo /home type defaults 0 0" >>/etc/fstab` - but can I be sure that `/tmp` is not used by any programs when the `fstab` is applied?

---

**I am using** either Ubuntu or plain Debian or Debian/[Grml](http://www.grml.org/) - this would not make much difference I guess.

**What I have read so far:**

- The internet is full of advice to just add `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs <optionns> 0 0` - but I am unsure.
- I found this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5503) on what to do when `/tmp` is full without rebooting (in short: It's best to reboot anyway, except maybe for a union mount).
- The [Deban policy] does not explain where to add the mount, or when the first access to `/tmp` may happen. More helpful are `/etc/init.d/README` and `/etc/rcS/README` on my Ubuntu ([read them online](https://gist.github.com/2434249)).

**Background:** I am going to use some Debian flavor on my Netbook (no HD, 8 GB SSD, 1 GB RAM - will double the RAM when neccessary). *I am not low on memory.* Some tasks are much too slow (building medium-sized C programs or compiling PDF from TeX both take 5+ seonds), but they take no time on a tmpfs. I want to mount a tmpfs on /tmp to accelerate them.

Comment: I am now confident that mounting `/tmp` from the `/etc/fstab` is not any problem. *Thanks to Gilles, Nils, Mikel, emory, CodeGnome!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be explicitly specified by the Debian policy, but Debian does support making `/tmp` a separate filesystem (as well as `/home`, `/var` and `/usr`). This is traditionally supported by unix systems. And I can confirm that making `/tmp` a tmpfs filesystem, and mounting it automatically via `/etc/fstab`, does work on Debian.

There is some difficulty in transitioning to `/tmp` on tmpfs on a live system, because of the files that are already in `/tmp` and cannot be copied. But no file in `/tmp` is expected to be saved across reboots. It is safe to mount a different filesystem to `/tmp` at the time the partitions in `/etc/fstab` are mounted.

Comment: Making /home, /tmp, /var/tmp a separate filesystem is an  official NSA policy.  I don't know about /var and /usr.  Why are they recommended?

Comment: I always found transitioning `/tmp` very easy. I usually do `mv /tmp /tmp.old; mkdir -m 0 /tmp; mount /tmp; ln -s /tmp.old/* /tmp` after adding the said line to the fstab. Then the open files in the old `/tmp` are to be found in `/tmp.old` and nevertheless can be accessed via `/tmp`. Then I check if they are used any longer, and after the next reboot, I remove `/tmp.old`.

Answer (score 1):

**tmp** should not be used for persistent data

The LSB (Linux Standard Base) defines in the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE17) (FilesystemHierarchyStandard) 2.3 that

"Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are preserved between invocations of the program."

As [Gilles has pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37033), this may include **sockets** for running programs. Most of these programs are propably network services, located in runlevel 2 or 3.

To get detail info for your system:

`cd /etc/init.d ; grep tmp *` should show you usage of tmp during boot.

Do an additional `grep mktemp *` to look for higher-level usage of tmp.

Every program should use tmp only very shortly.

On your running system do `fuser /tmp/* ; fuser /tmp/*/*` and so on to check for running processes blocking tmp.

Apart from that /etc/fstab should be a standard place for mounting filesystems - why should you not add it with "1 2"?

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. On a desktop machine, there is a file in `tmp` that is in permanent use: `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`, the socket that all X programs use to communicate to the server.

Comment: @Gilles: Since in my case, everything will happen before X comes into play, this should be okay.

Comment: @Nils: Thank you for this cheap and valuable hint! Though I did read some stuff about or under `/etc/init.d`, using `grep` really is enlighting!

Comment: @Nils Your judgement that it's very bad style is not shared by the authors of X servers, or other programs that put sockets in `/tmp`. This opinion that files in `/tmp` are short-lived is not a common one. The key characteristics of `/tmp` is that the files there are not expected to survive a reboot.

Comment: @Nils This doesn't contradict the common practice of putting sockets in `/tmp` in any way. These sockets are not supposed to survive an instance of the server. It doesn't prevent the server (and hence the socket) from remaining for a long time — for a desktop machine, typically, from a few seconds after boot to a few seconds before shutdown.

Comment: @Nils Not really, it's your first sentence that I find misleading. `/tmp` is pretty much defined by not being kept *across reboots*, and also sometimes for deleting *unused* files. But on a machine with long uptime, files that are in use can remain in `/tmp` for as long as the machine is up. P.S. I don't think I have anything to add to this debate, if you really want to continue I'm almost always logged in to chat.

Comment: @Gilles I changed my answer - so let`s delete this discussion from the comments...

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should `telinit 1` before mounting over your current /tmp directory. In single-user mode, there should be no files in /tmp that are required for system operation, so you should be able to clean out the directory, unmount it (if it's a separate partition), and then mount something else at that mount point before returning to multi-user mode.

To ensure /tmp is not in use:

1. When /tmp is a mounted filesystem, `fuser -m /tmp` will verify that no processes are currently using the mount point before you modify it.
2. When /tmp is not a separate filesystem, `find /tmp -print0 | xargs -0 fuser` will give you similar results.

You might also consider mounting a separate tmpfs filesystem, and exporting TMPDIR (or your compiler's similar environment variables) to make use of it. That would give you the benefit of a tmpfs scratch space without requiring system-wide changes.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/fstab` is only used when something runs `mount`.

The three times I can think of:

- during system boot (on a Debian system, this is early during boot via `/etc/rcS.d/S10mountall.sh`)
- when superuser runs `mount -a`
- when superuser runs `mount <mount point mentioned in /etc/fstab>`

If you're saying you want to create a new tmpfs for programs you're about to run, but without rebooting, I think you'll have to mount it somewhere other than `/tmp` so you don't break programs that are already running.

Why not just

```
mkdir /tmpnew
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmpnew
TMPDIR=/tmpnew make...
```